# How to make nested model for complicated form - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have got a pretty complicated Angular form-configurator with three columns:

1) **Categories** - shows major categories

2) **Items** - shows items for selected major category

3) **Parameters** show parameters for selected item

Key functionality:

- Items could be selected from several different categories;
- There is an "Enable" checkbox in each item's parameters, so several items could be selected simultaniously in each category;
- Also each item has several common parameters and could have some individual parameters (arbitrary number of them);

I need to create model that should be able to map to JSON like this:

```js
{
  "project_id": "1",
  "name": "some name",
  "category_1": [
    {
      "param_1": 10,
      "items": [
        {
          "common_param_1": "echo", 
          "common_param_2": "Simple hello", 
          "individual_params": { 
            "name": "John", 
            "age": "18"
            // arbitrary number of other individual params here
          },
          "common_param_3": 10.0,
          "common_param_4": 1000,
          "common_param_5": 50.0
        }
        // arbitrary number of items here
      ],
      "param_2": "seq"
    }
  ]
  // several other categories
}
```

Current state of form with ngModel:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  <h1>Add config</h1>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" ngModel class="text_input" placeholder="item configuration name here..">
  Schedule: <input type="text" name="schedule" ngModel class="text_input" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS">

  <table class="selection_table">
    <tr>
      <td width=15%>
        <div style="height: 100%">
          <b>categorys:</b>
          <select name="category" size="10" ngModel style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 93.5%" (click)="select_category($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let category of categories" value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width=35%>
        <div style="height: 100%">
          <b>Items:</b>
          <select name="items" ngModel size="10" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 70%" (click)="select_item($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
          </select>
          <div style="height: 24%">
            <div style="float: left"><input type="checkbox">Show only selected items</div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 22px; width: 150px">Param_1: <input type="text" name="param_1" ngModel="180" size="5" value="180" style="text-align: center"></div>
            <div style="float: right; margin-top: 1px;text-align: left;width: 130px">
              <div><input type="radio" name="param_2">Mode_1</div>
              <div><input type="radio" name="param_2">Mode_2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width=50%>
        <div style="height: 100%">
          <b>Parameters</b>
          <div>
            Common param 3
            <input type="range" name="common_param_3_slider" ngModel="100" min="1" max="100" value="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value" style="position: relative; top:7px; width:330px">
            <input type="text" name="common_param_3_value" value="100" oninput="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" style="width: 30px; text-align: center">%
          </div>
          <div>
            Common param 5
            <input type="range" name="common_param_5_slider" ngModel="100" min="1" max="100" value="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value" style="position: relative; top:7px; width:330px">
            <input type="text" name="common_param_5_value" value="100" oninput="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" style="width: 30px; text-align: center">%
          </div>

          <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 30px; text-align: right; width: 250px">
            <div *ngFor="let param of params" style="margin-top: 10px">
              {{param | lowercase}}:
              <select name="{{param}}" ngModel style="position: relative">
                <option *ngFor="let option of options[param]" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">common_param_5: <input type="text" name="common_param_5" ngModel="30" size="5" value="30" style="text-align: center"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="position:absolute;top: 420px; left: 1000px"><input type="checkbox" (click)="select_enable($event)">Enable</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="position: relative; left:446px">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
```

Currently I've got this handler for onSubmit():

```js
onSubmit(myForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(myForm.value);
}
```

But it maps to "flat" JSON and ngModel created by form above doesn't support nesting.

I've tried to make model as a separate class, but I didn't find how to make it "dynamic" to support arbitrary number of paramters and items in different categories.

Could you please share your thoughts on how could I solve this problem?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't spend a lot of time digging through your HTML, but a general answer to your question is to use `ngModelGroup`. That allows you to nest the controls to match a nested structure.

Here is an example:

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup="address">
  <label>Street:</label>
  <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>

  <label>Zip:</label>
  <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>

  <label>City:</label>
  <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
</fieldset>
```

This example is from this blog post: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html#ngmodelgroup-directive

Comment: Thanks for that! Really helpful :)